# How can I determine whether I have an Atlas Pass?

Tags: no-mans-sky

*Closely related:  [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/285396/5398](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/285396/5398_)*

---

I stopped playing No Man's Sky for a while and now I've come back to it.

Now that I'm in the game, I can't remember what I had done before (how apropos)

**How can I determine whether I have an Atlas Pass v1, v2, v3, or none at all?**

Comment: Simply check which recipe you have and craft the highest. Obtaining recipe is now more straighforward and faster: you just have to find and complete (save before ;) ) manufacturer facility (building sentinel guards and door you have to destroy) and you get 2 tokens, which you can choose on what to spend, so basically you need 2 facilities to open v3. But depending on how long time ago you stop playing (can you tell us?) it may be well worth to start a new game.

Comment: @Sinatr Why not post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @Wondercricket, I didn't play NMS recently and I want to clarify something. Feel free to repeat my words in your answer if you are more confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to determine which Atlas Pass you already have is:

Atlas V1: Try to open [Cargo Drops](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Cargo_Drop#Cargo_Drop_.28barrel_type.29) (the red barell shaped thing)

Atlas V2: Try to unlock doors inside planetary buildings

Atlas V3: Try to unlock doors located in space stations